# Detecting a click after a new element is loaded after the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a simple Chrome Plugin - however I have come to an issue.

I am trying to detect a click on a div using a simple `getElementById` - however as the api call happens after the DOM is loaded the JS cannot 'find' any div's and gives an error and doesn't do anything after I click on the element.

How do I detect the click, after the data from the API has loaded? I have included some of my code below:

Thanks

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

      var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');

      checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function () {

        inputBox = document.getElementById("postcodeInput").value

        console.log(inputBox)

        let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open('get', "https://api.getaddress.io/find/" + inputBox + "/?api-key=SECRET&expand=true", false);
        xml.send(null);
        var data = xml
        var arr = xml.responseText
        var data = JSON.parse(arr)
        var postcode = data.postcode
        var addresses = data.addresses

        console.log(addresses)
        document.getElementById("postcode").innerHTML = postcode;

        var text = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
          text += "<div id='addressClick' name=" + i + ">" + addresses[i].line_1 + "</div>" + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = text;

        clickFunc()
      }, false);
    }, false);

    function clickFunc() {
      var rowBox = document.getElementById("addressClick");

      rowBox.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('asd');
      }, true);
    }
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Address Search</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Address Search</h3>
  <input type="text" id='postcodeInput' name="postcodeInput" value="KW1 4YT">
  <button id="checkPage">Search</button>
  <div class='results'>
    <h3>Results - <span id='postcode'></span></h3>
    <p id='data'></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<style>
  body {
    width: 200px
  }

  #addressClick:hover {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer
  }
</style>
```

Comment: You could assign event listeners to newly inserted items or, use `delegated event handlers` - ie: register event listener on unchanging parent element somewhere up the DOM, monitor events on that parent and check if they are of interest to your script. or possibly use `DOM MutationObserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an `EventListener` to all the body and, at every click, detect if the clicked element is the desired one:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => window.alert(event.target.innerText));
```

This can sound like an aggressive solution, but it's way less invasive than a `MutationObserver`